# Bind handler to multiple elements with similar IDs

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of elements, the `id` attributes of them are something like `element_num`, where the `num` is the number of element. I want it so that when I click on one of these elements it gets deleted.

The first question is how to use a selector to find these elements (I think I need something like regex here).

The second question is how to obtain the clicked element id to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery you can select elements by

```
$("#id") for id
$(".class") for class
$("elem") for an element type, like <div>
```

say you have 30 divs (with class .removable) on a page and you want to delete the one that is clicked on, you would do something like this:

```
$(".removable").click(function()
{
    alert("removing: "+$(this).attr("id")); 
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind to all of them and  delete them like:

```
$("[id*='element_num']").click(function() {
    // this.id is the id if you need it.
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The `*=` selector get's any element with an id containing the segment. Ideally you would wrap all these deletable items in a container so you can use DOM selection instead.

[`*=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), [`.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 0):

You could add some class to these elements, so you could select all of them and bind a delete action on the click event, just using a class selector like <strike>`$(.removable)`</strike> $(".removable")

Also, if you use a class for this, you could just use the id of the element for the real id number, and then you'd just get the element id to get the real number id with this

<strike>`$(this).attr('id')`</strike> `this.id`

Comment: -1 for the oxymoron `$(this).attr("id")` Please use `this.id`

Comment: @Raynos: What? You mean you don't always pass objects to functions which return your object wrapped in a set of utilities that allow you to extract a property by calling a method and passing a string? ;o)

Comment: @patrick_dw You need to wrap them more `Enterprise($(this)).getMethods().executeMethod(EnterPrise($(this)).getMethodNames().get("id"))`

Comment: Since this is already sitting at -1 I won't further downvote, but also -1 for your incorrect-syntax class selector. (You would need to quote your string.)

Comment: @Raynos: Excellent! I'm adding that idea to my new library for coders who charge by the character!

Comment: Thx for the comments. I've fixed it. It wasnt necessary to make fun of me though.

Comment: @ONe You're still doing it wrong. It's `this.id` not `$(this).id`. @patrick_dw you really should [join the darkside](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

Comment: Sorry @ONe. Just teasing a little. Don't take it too personally. :o)

Comment: @Raynos: It goes against my naturally anti-social disposition. ;o)